# How to get reminder of XOR division in calc.exe?

Tags: binary, calculator, division, xor

I would like to understand how I can calculate manually CRC encoding.

I have message to be sent like 1110 1101 1011 0111 and code generator 11001. In order to encode the message I add five zeros to the message (1110 1101 1011 0111 00000) and divide it by generator 11001.

I should receive 1011000000100100 with reminder 0000100 - in such a case I can replace five zeros with right part of reminder (00100). This is what I can see in the example found somewhere.

But I cannot calculate it with Windows calculator (calc.exe). I launch programmer's mode in calc.exe, type 1110 1101 1011 0111 00000 XOR 110001 and receive 111011011011011010001 instead of 1011000000100100. (Ordinary division gives 1001101100111110 which is not correct value as well).

How can I perform XOR division (or rather obtain reminder from this division) on two binary numbers?

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

XOR by itself isn't a division.  The calculator tool is just doing a single bit-wise exclusive-or of the two binary numbers (with the shorter number assumed to be padded with leading zeros as necessary) and returning the result.

```
111011011011011100000 XOR
000000000000000110001 =
111011011011011010001
```

What you are looking for is an iterative shift-and-XOR process, which calc.exe doesn't do.  If you want to do it manually, you're going to need a pencil and paper.